# Mysql Result Return Problem

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, fuelphp

I'm creating a project in FuelPHP, with php + mysql. 
I have this database query (I'm not using their built in query builder because its just a pain in the ass for complex queries).

```
$sql = DB::query('
    SELECT game_id, lati, longi,
       acos(sin    (' . $lat .  ') 
     * sin (radians(    lati     ))
     + cos         (' . $lat .  ') 
     * cos (radians(lati)) 
     * cos (radians(longi) - ' . $lon . ')) 
     *' . $R . ' AS D 
        FROM (
            SELECT game_id, lati, longi
            FROM games 
            WHERE lati > ' . $minLat . 
        ' AND lati <' . $maxLat . 
        ' AND  longi > ' . $minLon . 
        ' AND longi < ' . $maxLon . 
        ') AS firstcut
            WHERE 
                acos(sin    (' . $lat .  ') 
     * sin (radians(    lati     ))
     + cos         (' . $lat .  ') 
     * cos (radians(lati)) 
     * cos (radians(longi) - ' . $lon . ')) 
     *' . $R . '<' . $rad . 
     ' ORDER BY D');
```

If I execute this and print_r(result) the number of rows is displayed i.e 2.

However I cant treat, or convert this result into an array, so I cant

```
foreach($result as $row) { echo $row['id'] . ' + ' . $row['D']}
```

Or something similar.

If I paste this code and replace the php variables with real values into phpmyadmin, I get the green 'The query was executed successfully' message but no rows are returned (two rows should be returned, there is not even a 'This query returned zero rows' message). 
I dont have much experience with this kind of nested/complex sql queries, so any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you do a var_dump($result) and tell us what the output is?

Comment: show us the whole block of code that creates the query, runs it, and `var_dump`'s the result

Comment: I'm not sure its that process thats giving me a strange result, as phpmyadmin gives me a stange result as well (non-zero return, but does not display any rows)

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass `DB::SELECT` as the second param for `DB::query()`.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use the as_array method from the database result. Or take a look here: http://fuelphp.com/docs/classes/database/usage.html#results

Comment: The as_array method does not work. Its the default method I use for all database usage in fuel.

Comment: You could echo \DB::last_query(); and see if the query executed is actually the right one?